# How to add product to cart without customer session(as a guest user) in magento, programatically?

Tags: php, magento, session, cart

I want to add items to cart from my  magento module. so i used the below code with the session.

```
$customerId=108;
$customer=getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

$storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite(1)->getStoreIds();
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
              ->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)
              ->loadByCustomer($customer);    
if($quote)
{
   $collection = $quote->getItemsCollection(false);
   if ($collection->count() > 0)
   {
      foreach( $collection as $item )
      {
         Mage::log($item->getQty());
      }      
   }
}
```

Now i want to  do the same without the session for guest user. I searched for the solution but no luck, Is there any way in magento to do this?
Thanks

Comment: check this link  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30417/programmatically-add-items-to-cart-and-assign-to-guest-user
hope it will give your answer